# How can I check if the multidimensional array is empty

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list

I have created the array like this:

```
a = np.empty((2,3), dtype=object)
```

How can I check if it's empty? I have used the following methods without any success.

```
a = np.empty((2,3), dtype=object)
#1:
if a == []: 
   print("Empty list!")
else:
   print('Not empty')

#2:
if not a:
   print("List is empty")
else:
   print('Not empty')

#3:
if a:
   print('Not empty')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For python3, this is one of the moves:

```
if a.all()==None: 
   print("Empty list!")
else:
   print('Not empty')
```